# CreateSQLQuery works but QueryOver doesn't with NHibernate

Tags: c#, mysql, nhibernate, model-view-controller

So I'm trying to execute a basic select query from a table to return the rows. Right now I have an object representing the data in the table and is mapped in the hbm.xml file. As far as I know, the mapping is correct (it's a simple table with an auto-incrementing key and a string value).

When I do:

`session.CreateSQLQuery("SELECT * FROM db.table").List()`

for example, the resulting query works.

However, if I do:

`session.QueryOver<MyObject>().List()`

the result is null.

Comment: Can you post your mapping files and class for MyObject? Is the MyObject XML mapping an embedded resource? Is the table name in MyObject set to "table"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually when this happens it is because your XML file is not marked as an embedded resource in  your project.

See here:-

[image]