# NHibernate doesn't see table, MappingException

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I thought I knew my way around NHibernate, but I must be doing something stupid. I have a table/class called Category. When I pull data from my GetAll method, nothing returns, but there are no errors either.

The class is:

```
namespace Model
{
    [Serializable]
    public partial class Category
    {
        public virtual int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
        public virtual DateTime UpdatedOn { get; set; }

        public virtual string Name { get; set; }

        public override bool Equals(object oneObject)
        {
            return oneObject is Category && (this.GetHashCode() == ((Category)oneObject).GetHashCode());
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return Id.ToString().GetHashCode();
        }

    }
}
```

Mapping file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" namespace="Model" assembly="Model" xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
    <class name="Category" lazy="true" table="`categories`"><!--test only!!-->
        <id name="Id" access="property" column="`category_id`">
            <generator class="native" />
        </id>
    <property name="Name" column="`name`" length="50" />
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

If I add a many-to-one reference in another table, then it errors with: `An association from the table manufacturer_categories refers to an unmapped class: Model.Category`.

It seems obvious to me that NHibernate is not recognizing my mapping file. What stupid thing am I missing?

Comment: Didja check for obvious things, like adding the .hbm part to the xml file, or making sure that it's set as Embedded Content?

Comment: @Cosmo_D -- Yes, I checked the .hbm.xml. What is the "Embedded Content" about?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16340974/createsqlquery-works-but-queryover-doesnt-with-nhibernate/16377359#16377359 for embedded resource

Comment: @Rippo - That was it! I didn't even think about checking the resource. It's a bit hard to debug something like that. If you want to post an answer, I'd gladly accept it. Thanks.

Comment: Answer added, glad it was as simple as this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked that your XML file is marked as an embedded resource?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Using full qualified name of the class, may solve the problem

```
<class name="Modle.Category" lazy="true" table="`categories`">
```

Also make sure that when configuring Nhibernate you have added the assembly containing  Category mapping file

```
Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
cfg.Configure();

// Add class mappings to configuration object
Assembly mappingAssembly = AssemblyContatingTheCategoryMappingXMLFile;
cfg.AddAssembly(mappingAssembly);
```

Another hint will be setting the xml file as `Embedded Resource` on properety tab

Comment: I added Some suggestions that may come in handy pal.